# Where clause in every API call in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I want a way where I can add a 'where' clause which will have an Id in all the API calls for Get, Update, Delete.

I'm using Middleware to achieve this. Below is my code:

```
module.exports = function(){
    return function parse(req, res, next) {
        // Add an 'and' filter that specifies the tenant in all requests. 
        req.query.filter = ({
            where: { tenantCompanyKey: '1a4f7513147aefc2a93ac7153df458fd' }
        });
        next();
    }
}
```

So when the query is executed it should look like :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts
         WHERE tenant_company_key = '1a4f7513147aefc2a93ac7153df458fd'
```

Comment: hi .. what is the question. is the middleware not working ?

Comment: It's working but giving me the unexpected result. That is the filter is not applied